# meaning of Elizabeth quote

Tags: meaning, quotes

> Men fight wars, women win them

What is the meaning of this quote?

Comment: What do the words say?

Comment: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/12/We_Can_Do_It!.jpg

Comment: @Hot Licks It was Elizabeth - to - be **II** who joined the Women's Auxiliary Territorial Service

Comment: I see this quote attributed to Elizabeth I all over the internet but nobody gives a source. I don't believe it.

Comment: Could the US have won WWII without women?

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a reference to the speech made by Queen Elizabeth I, on 9 August 1588 at Tilbury, at the time of the conflict with the Spanish Armada. It contained the words:

> I know I have the body of a weak, feeble woman; but I have the heart
>   and stomach of a king, and of a king of England too, and think foul
>   scorn that Parma or Spain, or any prince of Europe, should dare to
>   invade the borders of my realm; to which rather than any dishonour
>   shall grow by me, I myself will take up arms, I myself will be your
>   general, judge, and rewarder of every one of your virtues in the
>   field.

Wikipedia: Speech to the Troops at Tilbury.

Comment: This may favourably compare Elizabeth's rhetoric with Churchill's, but does it really address the question?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The question, unfortunately is not terribly explicit, and consists of  "I am unable to  understand the meaning of this quotation, if anyone can help please". My answer attempts to address that.

Comment: You're quite correct. The question needs clarifying or closing.

Comment: @StoneyB Well there is a perfectly good Wikipedia article on [Speech to the troops at Tilbury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_to_the_Troops_at_Tilbury) in which it explains that the text was found in a letter of Lionel Sharp date 1624. I certainly heard about it long before there was an internet. What sort of evidence would you want? I'm sure I could find it in a history book, if you feel that would be more authoritative. You are not suggesting this is "fake news" are you? There have been people who have agued that she was in reality male.

Comment: @WS2 Apologies: I wasn't referring to the Tilbury speech but to the "Man fights woman wins" in OP's question. I'll move it up to the Question.

Comment: It looks vaguely like women being the power behind the throne; men fighting only while woman maintain morale; keep the home fires burning.

As StoneyB said the phrase is attributed to Good Queen Bess on the WWW but with no provenance. Equally, it doesn’t sound the kind of thing Elizabeth II might have said; she’s not know for saying things remotely like that…

The Tilbury pep-talk is a stirring speech but how could it be relevant? Its place in history, as in Hollywood, is as an exhortation by a leader to an army. Coming from a female, alluding in one word to her femininity, hardly matters.

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin What exactly is it in my answer that you take issue with? I don't believe I mentioned Elizabeth II.

Comment: @WS2 No, it was Edwin who mentioned QEII

About your answer, didn't I say the Tilbury pep-talk was a stirring speech and ask how could it be relevant?

Comment: Thanks guys for answering, and sorry for any issue in my question, i will try to write more precise next time.. gratefull to all..